# Enable custom scripts in _Layout.cshtml ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building MVC 5, SignalR Real time notification app, I want place my working scripts in _Layout.cshtml, because for example on add new item I want display toastr notification, but scripts placed it _Layout.cshtml not working, I've added scripts in BundleConfig, but it's not working.
Note: everything works fine on every page except _Layout.cshtml
can anyone help me? Lot of thanks.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": true,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
    "preventDuplicates": false,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "5000",
    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};
$(function () {

    var notificationhub = $.connection.notificationHub;

    notificationhub.client.displayMessage = function (message) {

        toastr.success(message);
        //$('#notification').html(message);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start();

}); });
```

This script works if I'm place it on  any page in  `@section scripts{}`
My _Layout scripts section  looks like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/notifications")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

But this way not works.
how can I implement my script correctly in my _Layout page to  display notifications everywere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your _Layout.cshtml page, the portion `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` is only serving as a placeholder for pages that implement the `@sections scripts {}`, hence why you are seeing the behavior you are. This is part of the layout engine for Razor.

For more information on how that all works, here is an article on ScottGu's blog that may help: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)

In order to get the script bundle to be included on the _Layout base page, you need to directly render it on the page, just like the other bundles are being rendered. It should look something like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
```

**Where `scripts` is the name of the script bundle you wish to include.

Now if you want to just directly put the script on the page, you can do that as well. Just make sure you enclose it properly with the correct HTML syntax. And remember that any page that uses the _Layout.cshtml as it's layout will have all the scripts included on _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of thanks to ryancdotnet, [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)
Was realy helpfull, so I will as solution to place my scripts on  every page where I want to  use script.